# Can't resolve NameValueCollection with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, namevaluecollection

I am using Autofac 2.1.12 to handle my dependency injection, and am having trouble with one specific issue. I can't seem to resolve a NameValueCollection dependency.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(NameValueCollection collection) { }
}

static class Run
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<NameValueCollection>();
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>();

        using (var scope = builder.Build())
            scope.Resolve<Foo>();
    }
}
```

It will crash with an unhandled DependencyResolutionException:

> Circular component dependency
>   detected:  Foo ->
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
>   -> System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.

However, if I replace NameValueCollection with any other type, the code works fine.

Am I doing something wroing, is there something special about the NameValueCollection type that I am missing, or is this an issue with Autofac itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. See [Autowiring](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Autowiring):

> Autofac automatically chooses the constructor with the most parameters that are able to be obtained from the container.

Try registering `NameValueCollection` like so (not sure if this will work, though):

```
builder.RegisterType<NameValueCollection>().UsingConstructor();
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
builder.Register(c => new NameValueCollection());
```

Comment: Add some parentheses to that `new NameValueCollection()` and all will be swell :)